# How to read different workouts in HEALTHKIT SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, healthkit

I’m new in Swift and I need to extract all data related to workouts from HealthKit and use it in JavaScript (I'm making a React Native app), so I made a query but its predicate only pass one workout e.g .cycling, what I need is to get all workouts, even if the user has it or not, let's say: get all workouts recorded (even if they are differents) by the user in a list.

I need: Running {...} Cycling {....} Pilates {...}

but I'm getting : Cycling 1 Cycling 2 Cycling 3

In brief, I need a predicate to do this. my code:
[image]

Comment: How  about making the workout type a parameter to your read function and then calling it once for each workout type that you need?

Comment: Do you mean harcoding the workout types??

Comment: Yes, you would have to.

Comment: thanks, I created an array with each instance and then I made a loop to iterate each workout type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing a nil predicate to the `HKSampleQuery` to retrieve all workouts regardless of their type.